# OAauth2 Authorization Server - external login page and redirect after login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to integrate [Spring Auth Server](https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server) with an existing authentication provider, IBM WebSeal in the context of an OICD flow.

Basically, I want Spring Auth Server to use Webseal login page to authenticate a user (coming from a SPA/front-end app) and then return a JWT token to the front-end app.

On successful authentication, WebSeal redirects to a configurable URL adding a header to the request. This header contains the actual username and signals that the user is authenticated.

I was able to implement the flow and have Spring Auth Server use the external login page, but I don't understand to which URL should WebSeal redirect. Do I need to create an explicit end-point (such as `/authenticated`)?
It seems that the OAUTH2 spec doesn't define an explicit endpoint for this particular case.

Adding diagram for clarity:

```
                       +----------------+                 +------------------+                           
                       |                |                 |                  |                           
                       |                |                 |                  |                           
                       |  FRONT END APP |                 |   BACK-END APP   |                           
                       |                |                 |   (SPRING BOOT)  |                           
                       |                |                 |                  |                           
                       |                |                 |                  |                           
                       +---|----|-------+                 +------------------+                           
                           |    |                                                                        
         4 - /oauth2/token |    | 1 - /oauth2/authorize?                                                 
                           |    |                                                                        
                           |    |                                                                        
                           |    |                                                                        
                       +---|----|-------+                  +----------------+                            
                       |                | 3 - send header  |                |                            
                       |     SPRING     --------------------                |                            
                       |      AUTH      |                  |   WEBSEAL      |                            
                       |     SERVER     -------------------|                |                            
                       |                | 2 - show form    |                |                            
                       |                |                  +----------------+                            
                       +----------------+
```

Thanks!